# Call non static method from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to call non static method from another page

I cant use of static method

I have a method in master page

Now, I want calling method in another page from master page method

Master Page:

```
protected void Pagination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Count = Convert.ToInt32(DRCount.Text);
    LinkButton LinkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    int Select = Convert.ToInt32(LinkButton.Text);
    int Num2 = Count * Select;
    int Num1 = Num2 - Count;
    **//Calling GetData method in 01.aspx** 
}


01.aspx.cs page:

public void GetData(int Num1, int Num2)
{
    int Count = Convert.ToInt32(this.Master.Count);
    int PriceSort = Convert.ToInt32(this.Master.Price);
    string NameSort = this.Master.Name.ToString();...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to `new` another ASP.NET page from codebehind. Instead move the code to a  class in which you can utilize the shared logic.

Comment: You mean ASP.NET uses OO ? o_O

Comment: @Bart most people programming in it don't, but that doesn't mean you can't. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do

```
YourClassName variableName = new YourClassName();
```

Then call the method as `variableName.GetDate(1,2);`.

You'll have to change the method from `private` to `public` in order to call it from another class.

Further reading on [Access Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a method that's shared between various pages, it shouldn't really be declared in a specific page. Good design principles would say to make it part of a separate class. Let's say you call it "MyDataClass". (Obviously choose something more appropriate).

```
protected void Pagination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int Count = Convert.ToInt32(DRCount.Text);
  LinkButton LinkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
  int Select = Convert.ToInt32(LinkButton.Text);
  int Num2 = Count * Select;
  int Num1 = Num2 - Count;

  MyDataClass dataClass = new MyDataClass();
  dataClass.GetData();
}
```

And in another file called MyDataClass.cs

```
public class MyDataClass
{
  public void GetData(int Num1, int Num2)
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

That way you can use it in as many pages as you need, or even easily re-use it in another project. This sort of abstraction of responsibilities is one of the fundamental things to learn about object-oriented programming in languages such as C#.

Answer (score 0):

The access modifier needs to be changed from private to public.
Additionally, all variables you need seek to update in the other method, need to be accessible. (Read codecasters answer for the more profound answer specific to your problem)

Make these changes:

```
protected void Pagination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Count = Convert.ToInt32(DRCount.Text);
    LinkButton LinkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    int Select = Convert.ToInt32(LinkButton.Text);
    int Num2 = Count * Select;
    int Num1 = Num2 - Count;
    var otherClass = new OtherClass();
    otherClass.GetData(Num1,Num2);
}


01.aspx.cs page:

public void GetData(int Num1, int Num2)
{
    int Count = Convert.ToInt32(this.Master.Count);
    int PriceSort = Convert.ToInt32(this.Master.Price);
    string NameSort = this.Master.Name.ToString();...
}
```

I'm not sure what your other class is called, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you tell me a sampel until to see it?

Comment: I think your answer adeptly covers why this shouldn't be a problem, I was trying to outline the general problem. Updated my answer to help OP with his specific question though.